# What is the variable for having multiple minibuffers?

Tags: minibuffer

I remember a while back that I could open a minibuffer within a minibuffer.

But now I can't seem remember what the variable was or if it was package specific.


I'm using Ivy, Swiper, and Counsel.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature is called [(emacs) Recursive Edit](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recursive-Edit.html), it's disabled by default, you can enable it via

```
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
```

With Recursive Edit enabled, you might also want to enable `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode` to indicate current Recursive Edit depth in the minibuffer prompt.

```
(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode)
```